# Solving conflicting CSS. How to add selector?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a little module for personal use inside an existing webapp. (fyi, WHMCS). To style the module output, I'm using [a template](https://themeforest.net/item/limitless-responsive-web-application-kit/13080328).
However, now it looks like those CSS stylesheets are conflicting with the original (from the webapp), and the module CSS is also applied to the webapp (which screws the view completely.

As far as I am aware, I could solve this by adding an extra div to all my module output pages, like this

```
<body>
    <!-- Main navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-indigo">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="../modules/addons/webcanyonerp/assets/images/logo_light.png" alt=""></a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right visible-xs-block">
                <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mobile"><i class="icon-tree5"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-mobile">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-git-compare"></i>
                        <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right">Git updates</span>
                        <span class="badge bg-warning-400">9</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
                        <div class="dropdown-content-heading">
                            Git updates
                            <ul class="icons-list">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-sync"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
......
</body>
```

Becomes:

```
 <body>
<div class="mymodulecss">
        <!-- Main navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-indigo">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="../modules/addons/webcanyonerp/assets/images/logo_light.png" alt=""></a>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right visible-xs-block">
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-mobile"><i class="icon-tree5"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-mobile">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="icon-git-compare"></i>
                            <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right">Git updates</span>
                            <span class="badge bg-warning-400">9</span>
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
                            <div class="dropdown-content-heading">
                                Git updates
                                <ul class="icons-list">
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-sync"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
    ......
</div>
    </body>
```

So then I can limit the css to "mymodulecss".
Then, after that, I have to alter all (module) css files, so they are only applied to "mymodulecss"

Can you tell me if that approach is correct, and what the easiest way is to alter the css so it looks at the "mymodulecss" selector?

Thanks!!

Comment: maybe <section> is better than <div> in this case.

Comment: for the css use `.mymodulecss` before all what you want to modify. For example `.mymodulecss div .navbar {Css}`

Comment: If I understood you correctly: Yes, your approach is correct. The easiest way to alter existing CSS is to add new classes to override them (Or if you know what youre doing editing the source). I wrote a small guide a few weeks ago to prevent similar issues from the start: [Rules to Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909338/grid-do-not-have-margins-in-bootstrap/36909943#36909943)

Answer (score 1):

You can try deploying `:nth-of-type(n)` to style declarations you want to take precedence.

The *pseudo-class* `:nth-of-type(n)` will give style declarations increased specificity (overriding the cascade), without necessitating any update or alteration to the mark-up.

For example:

**Local CSS:**

```
aside:nth-of-type(n) {
background-color: red;
}
```

**External CSS:**

```
aside {
background-color: blue;
}
```

The `background-color` of every `<aside>` will remain `red`, even though the `background-color` is re-declared as `blue`, later in the cascade (in the external CSS).

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't have any control on the loading of the original (WHMCS) css. The sources are encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

First try to move around the `<link>` so the one your want to take precedence is loaded last.

For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="limitless-reseponsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mymodulecss.css"> <!-- The styles in here will take precedence over the other two -->
```

Source: [What is the order of loading the CSS files in a HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067455/what-is-the-order-of-loading-the-css-files-in-a-html-page)

Also you might want to try adding `!important` to the end of the important styles

For example

```
  div {
    padding: 15px !important;
  }
```

**Edit**: As Paul said, this is not best practice.

Comment: Careful with using !important though, you can always risk having it break your site if your selector wasn't specific enough.

Comment: Only use `!important` if there is no other way left. e.g. overriding inline style.

Comment: That would indeed be an option, but I can't alter this since I don't have control of how the original CSS is loaded. I only can add extra lines which are loaded after the original CSS in the head section

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

```
<div class="mymodulecss">
```

and using Less:

[add selector to each line in css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310337/add-selector-to-each-line-in-css-file/38310440#38310440)