# add selector to each line in css file

Tags: css, regex

I have to add a specific id selector (#mymodule) to each CSS line. Given that there are about 20000 lines, I don't want to do this manually :).

I tried to match with regex in notepad++ using:

```
^((?!}|\s\s).)*$
```

But I get an invalid error.
Trying not to re-invent the wheel, and probably I'm not the first who wants to do this, does anyone have a working regex string, or maybe some other method to achieve this?

Comment: An example input and example output would help anybody.

Comment: Why can't you try find `{` and replace with `,#mymodule { ` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is using [Less](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules)/[Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide) that allows you to nest css selectors

You can use [this](http://lesstester.com/) online editor to generate your new CSS, just paste your CSS and wrap it with your id, compile it...and you're done!

```
#mymodule {
    .class1 {
        color: red;
    }
    #selector {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer for sure. Even if you don't want to use a preprocessor for your project, or don't want to set it up today. It would be super quick to compile the CSS with the new selector prepended to each selector, and you would most likely get some whitespace and formatting stuff cleaned up in the process.