# trying to float three divs to the left center and right using bootsrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to float three divs to the left center and right and there should all be horizontally the same. This is my attempt:

### HTML

```
//to be centered div
<div style="float:center">

    <form>
    </form>

    <form>
    </form>

</div>
//to be floated to the left
<div style="float:left" id="active-container" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered">
        <p style="color:#fff; font-size:15px;"><strong>FLOATED TO THE LEFT </strong></p>

        <div id="active_users">
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

//to be floated to the right
<div style="float:right" id="engaged-container" class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered">
        <p style="color:#fff; font-size:15px;"><strong>FLOATED TO THE RIGHT </strong></p>

        <div id="engaged_users">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

My challenge is that the three divs floated to the left, center and right but they never began at the position, only the left and right divs are at the same position.

Please how do I float the three divs to the left center and right and starting at the same position that is making them horizontally aligned.

Comment: You should maybe take a look into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) - also possible duplicate of [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div)

Comment: I am using bootstrap...

Comment: _“I am using bootstrap...”_ – hardly … You are rather _violating_ bootstrap, by applying stuff like float to row elements (and inventing your own values on the way, `float:center` – that doesn’t even exist.) You should probably _start_ with _one_ row, that has three columns. Throw in some of the offset classes, if the column widths don’t add up to 12.

Comment: Do you mean if I need bootsrap? Yes I do for sake of responsiveness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the idea that you are new to Bootstrap, here take this answer and read through the documentation urself.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    //to be centered div
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
        <form>
        </form>
    </div>

    //to be floated to the left
    <div id="active-container" class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
        <p style="color:#fff; font-size:15px;"><strong>FLOATED TO THE LEFT </strong></p>
        <div id="active_users">
        </div>
    </div>

    //to be floated to the right
    <div id="active-container" class="col-md-4">
        <p style="color:#fff; font-size:15px;"><strong>FLOATED TO THE RIGHT </strong></p>
        <div id="engaged_users">
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap try the class [`.center-block`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)

> Set an element to `display: block` and center via `margin`. Available as a mixin and class.

```
// Class
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

// Usage as a mixin
.element {
  .center-block();
}
```

---

### Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="your-custom-class center-block">
            // your code here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have three divs not one

Comment: you do have 3 divs, adapt this example to your code :) `.center-block` requires `width` or `max-width` to be set. I've added `.your-custom-class` for this reason. You also might want to check this out: [Bootstrap Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909338/grid-do-not-have-margins-in-bootstrap/36909943#36909943)

Comment: dont understand this <div class="your-custom-class center-block">

Comment: `.your-custom-class` contains your custom CSS, maybe a background or whatever, it should contain `width` or `max-width` of your element

Comment: Can I do this <div style="width:100%" class="center-block">

Comment: Yes this does work, though centering a 100% block doesn't make much sense, does it? And inline style it bad practice. You seem to be new to html/css. Try to edit your elements via a CSS file or inside your `<style>`-Tags

Comment: Yes. This solution did not work as the three divs became vertically lapped on top of each other instead of three different columns of left center and right

Comment: use 3 columns `.col-md-4`. You should definitly take a deeper look into bootstraps syntax