# How to fixed a element in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create two columns with `col-md-8` and `col-md-4` with `col-md-4` contains my maps.

But I have a problem when I tried fixed map to `col-md-4`.

```js
function init_map() {
var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(45.430817, 12.331516);

var var_mapoptions = {
    center: var_location,
    zoom: 14
};

var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: var_location,
    map: var_map,
    title: "Venice"
});

var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
    var_mapoptions);

var_marker.setMap(var_map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

```css
.contact {
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  top: 800px;
  padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0%;
}

#map-container { height: 50px }

.service-container {
    background: url('http://images.indianexpress.com/2016/05/love-autumn-tree_759_thinkstockphotos-177812216.jpg');
    height:1000px;
    width: 1000px;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 179, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-container">
   <div class="layer">
      <div class="contact-maps">
         <div class="col-md-8 contact">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="col-md-6"></div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <h1>CONTACT</h1>
                  <h3>CENTRAL OFFICE</h3>
                  <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae laborum cum consequuntur assumenda itaque error dolore, molestiae illo fugiat. Illo praesentium ut mollitia dolorem quis vero quisquam culpa, voluptas eos.
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /.col-md-8 contact -->
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="map-container"></div>
         </div>
         <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /contact-maps -->
   </div>
   <!-- / .layer -->
</div>
<!-- service-container -->
```

I have two question:

1. Why I was set `<div id="map-container">` into `col-md-4` but it not show?
2. My website must responsive, but I must change at `top: 800px` create blank to another element before this element can appear.

I want it to show like this:

[http://i.imgur.com/rM95p0q.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNvv9.png)

Comment: Dont forget to use rows and cols alternating, every set of cols should be wrapped in a row. You might want to take a look at those examples: [Bootstrap Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909338/grid-do-not-have-margins-in-bootstrap/36909943#36909943)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question:
First of all, you have to use the Bootstrap grid system properly. BS columns must always be nested in rows ([BS grid tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)).

This would be the Bootstrap conform structure for your case:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 contact">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="map-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your map doesen't shows up, because you haven't loaded the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Do that with the following code:

```
 <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
 </script>
```

You have to [request an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) if you haven't so far.

PS: You should ask only one question per question.

Comment: I added this. But it doesn't show correct at `col-md-4`.

Comment: @HVnLcBIT - I edited my answer. Can you provide the output of your dev console? Are there any errors?

Comment: you can see my pen at here: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/bZyPkL

I added script map, and it shows but it does not load correctly at position of `col-md-4`

Comment: @HVnLcBIT - Read my answer again, you have to use the BS grid system properly.

Comment: Can you add a example with my case? Only need 1 example. I tried but all thing seem terrible.

Comment: @HVnLcBIT Just added an example for your case. Hope this helps.